# Failed to read blend file

Tags: blender

I recently made an animation about a week ago that i promised to my viewers i have gotten it up to 1950 frame.
One day i worked on the animation in the morning then left and put my computer on sleep as always it shut itself down when i came back and tried to open it i found that it says it was unreadable and incomplete.

this has happened to me twice now and im already getting sick of it how do i fix this problem i can't afford to give up on this animation and i don't have the time to remake it.

Comment: [This question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14101/935) could help. You may also be interested in the addon I wrote for [this one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40495/935).

Answer (score 0):

Go to where the .blend file was saved to and see if there is a .blend1 or .blend2 file and then open that in blender and re-save it.